# What ratio of example per class gives best results and least overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning

For an n-class classifier or predictor, how many positive (or negative?) examples of each of the n classes should I put into my training and testing sets for the best results?

I anticipate that during evaluation of my classifier the underlying distribution of samples will not be uniform. But if I keep these same ratios between the support of my examples in the testing data, I'm worried about over fitting on the classes that have the most examples.

So the question is, how many examples of each class should I use in during training, versus during validation (yes I know mma doesn't support validation sets yet), versus testing?

Here's an example with `Predict` showing the huge effects of the disturibution of class support on the results:

```
evenPlusExamples[n_] := (# -> Total@# &) /@ 
  Thread[{RandomInteger[1000, n]*2, RandomInteger[1000, n]*2}]

oddTimesExamples[n_] := (# -> Times @@ # &) /@

  Thread@{Take[Select[RandomInteger[n, n*10], OddQ], 100], 
    Take[Select[RandomInteger[n, n*10], OddQ], 100]}

balencedTraining = Join[evenPlusExamples[50], oddTimesExamples[50]];
unbalencedTraining = Join[evenPlusExamples[20], oddTimesExamples[150]];
balencedTesting = Join[evenPlusExamples[50], oddTimesExamples[50]];
unbalencedTesting = Join[evenPlusExamples[20], oddTimesExamples[150]];

bc = Predict[balencedTraining];
uc = Predict[unbalencedTraining];

bcbt = PredictorMeasurements[bc, balencedTesting];
bcut = PredictorMeasurements[bc, unbalencedTesting];
ucbt = PredictorMeasurements[uc, balencedTesting];
ucut = PredictorMeasurements[uc, unbalencedTesting];
```

[image]

And another example with `Classify`:

```
classes = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
testA = 0 <= # < 1 &;
testB = 1 <= # < 2 &;
testC = 2 <= # < 3 &;
testD = 3 <= # < 4 &;
perfectClassifier[x_Real] := 
  Which[testA@x, "A", testB@x, "B", testC@x, "C", testD@x, "D"];

balencedTrainingSet = (# -> perfectClassifier@#) & /@ 
   RandomReal[{0, 4}, 100];
unbalencedTrainingSet = (# -> perfectClassifier[#]) & /@ 
   Join[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 94], RandomReal[{1, 2}, 2], 
    RandomReal[{2, 3}, 2], RandomReal[{3, 4}, 2]];
balencedTestset = (# -> perfectClassifier@#) & /@ 
   RandomReal[{0, 4}, 100];
unbalencedTestset = (# -> perfectClassifier[#]) & /@ 
   Join[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 94], RandomReal[{1, 2}, 2], 
    RandomReal[{2, 3}, 2], RandomReal[{3, 4}, 2]];
uc = Classify[unbalencedTrainingSet];
bc = Classify[balencedTrainingSet];
```

this yields:

```
In[289]:= ClassifierMeasurements[bc, balencedTestset, "Accuracy"]
Out[289]= 0.97

In[290]:= ClassifierMeasurements[uc, balencedTestset, "Accuracy"]
Out[290]= 0.96

In[291]:= ClassifierMeasurements[bc, unbalencedTestset, "Accuracy"]
Out[291]= 1.

In[292]:= ClassifierMeasurements[uc, unbalencedTestset, "Accuracy"]
Out[292]= 0.99
```

This is definitely a stats question but it's so closely related to the usage these functions that I think it's best asked here.

Comment: I don't believe your question is really specific to Mathematica. Rather it is a question related to classifiers or classification algorithms and their use in general.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I can see what you mean. But I tried posting on other sites to no avail, and MMA-SE has many ML people so I casted into a mma question.

Comment: It would probably help if you described what you're trying to classify, and what happens if you don't balance the data at all? Normally you want the balance in both training set and test set to be the same as that which the classifier will receive when actually used. If the data is highly skewed, you're basically looking at a cost-approach: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UtilityFunction.html or sampling to solve it. Don't balance the test set either way - it's supposed to be an indication of how it will really work.